# how to set selected attribute in option for select drop down list

Tags: javascript, jquery

here is the html code

```
<select id="privacy" onChange="run()">
   <option value="1" selected="selected" >public</option>
   <option value="2">contact</option>
</select>
```

for`value=2,`i m selecting contact and this contact is appended in the list but its not showing as selected.below is the jquery code for appending but i m not getting where to set this selected atrribute.

```
$('#privacy').append($('<option> ', {
          text: postcontact
}));
```

Comment: you have jQuery, _please don't use inline event handlers_!

Answer (score 0):

USe `selected` attribute like this way

```
$('#privacy').append($('<option> ', {
    text: "postcontact",
    selected: "selected"
}));
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to use chaining at this context ,

```
$('#privacy').append($('<option> ', {text: postcontact ,value:2})).val(2);
```

or try this

```
$('#privacy').find("option").removeAttr("selected").end().append($('<option> ', {text: "postcontact" ,value:3,selected: "selected"})).val(3);
```

Comment: postcontact  is a string or variable ?

Comment: postcontact contains the value of phonenumber from phonebook.

Comment: can you reproduce the issues in fiddle